# FusionAuth Lambdas

Tags: authentication, fusionauth

I want to use the lambda feature of FusionAuth to populate the JWT depending on which app the user logins, because a same user can log into different apps and have several roles or groups in it. I don't want the JWT being populating of every role, being a role action that the user can make into the app(following the NIST RBAC model it will be permissions like 'read:attentions' or 'delete:tests') because it could be dozens of them (syze reasons), instead of that i want the JWT to be populated with the Groups the user has it that specific app. I tried assigning the roles property with empty array but not succeed. I know that the tool by default dont allow you to change the roles property, but there is a way to delete it?.

```js
function populate(jwt, user, registration) {
    jwt.group = registration.data.group;
    jwt.roles = [];
}
```

Anyway the token keeps having the roles, how can i remove them?

```
{
  "aud": "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
  "exp": xxxxxxx,
  "iat": xxxxxxx,
  "iss": "acme.com",
  "sub": "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
  "authenticationType": "PASSWORD",
  "email": "xxxxxxx@mail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "applicationId": "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
  "roles": [
    "read:attentions",
    "write:attentions"
  ],
  "group": "financer"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `roles` claim is reserved by FusionAuth and cannot be modified by a Lambda. There is an [open feature](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/387) that is scheduled to be complete in the upcoming release to loosen this restriction.

Once this feature is delivered you will have the option to remove or modify the `roles` claim.

The current reserved claims are outlined in the [JWT Populate Lambda](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/lambdas/jwt-populate) documentation.